# Camel 3.0-M2 missing method adviceWith in class: RouteDefinition

Tags: apache-camel

I see that in older version of camel usually people were using method `adviceWith` that was located in class: `RouteDefinition` - but in version 3.0 M2 - this method is not present.

https://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-swagger-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
            <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-rabbitmq</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
            <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
        </dependency>
```

Search in doc for class `RouteDefinition` and method `adviceWith`:

1) https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/3.0.0-M2

Here it is not present

2) https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.24.0

Here it is present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the question, it is not clear what your real question is. 
I presume, you are looking for an equivalent of `RouteDefinition.adviceWith` in Camel 3.0

In v3.0.0-M2, [RouteReifier.adviseWith](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/3.0.0-M2/org/apache/camel/reifier/RouteReifier.html) is what you are looking for.

Camel 3.0 is a major release and quite some API has changed, comparing to 2.x.
`RouteDefinition.adviceWith` is one of these cases as documented in the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#advicewith).

Comment: In Camel 3.7.4 RouteReifier.adviceWith has been removed

Answer (score 0):

In Camel 3.11 this has changed again and in the official examples only the lambda-style usage of adviceWith seems to compile.